# how to get expiration date of local windows account?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create C# method like this :

```
    void deleteExpiredAccounts(String Account,dateTime expirationDate)
    {
      if(expirationDate == DateTime.Now)
      {
        DirectoryEntry localDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer"); 
        DirectoryEntries users = localDirectory.Children;
        DirectoryEntry user = users.Find(Account); 
        users.Remove(user);
      }
    }
```

any idea will be appreciated..thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [`maxPwdAge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220201%28PROT.10%29.aspx)

Try

```
Console.Writeline( user.Properties["maxPwdAge"].ToString());
```

Comment: :S I tried it but the result was : "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection"

Comment: @Ragaei try `user.Properties["maxPwdAge"].Value.ToString()` or `foreach(object i in user.Properties["maxPwdAge"]){ Console.WriteLine(i);}`

Comment: @ Bala ...thanks youuuuuuuuuu: this is what i am searching : StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (object i in user.Properties["AccountExpirationDate"]) { sb.Append(i); }

        String ss = sb.ToString();

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me to get the password expiration date on both domain and local user accounts:

```
public static DateTime GetPasswordExpirationDate(string userId, string domainOrMachineName)
{
    using (var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + domainOrMachineName + '/' + userId + ",user"))
    {
        return (DateTime)userEntry.InvokeGet("PasswordExpirationDate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, LOCAL **accounts** do not expire so there is no such attribute.  Account expiration is of value for domain level accounts when you need to terminate a relationship for an account after a given period.

Now if you're talking about local account password expirations,that's a whole different story, but I can't imagine why you'd want to delete local machine users based on expired passwords.